# Upper bounds for moduli of contour integral.

Tags: complex-numbers

> Without evaluating the integral, show that
>   $$\left | \int_{C}\frac{dz}{\left ( z^2-1 \right )} \right |\leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$
>   where $C$is the arc of a circle $\left | z \right |=2$, from $z=2$ to $z=2i$  that lies in the first quadrant.I know
>   $$\left | \int_{C} f\left ( z \right )dz\right |\leq ML$$
>   $$L=\pi$$
>   $$\left | z^2-1 \right |\geq \left | \left | z \right |^2-\left ( 1 \right ) \right |=3$$
>   hence
>   $$\left | \int_{C}\frac{dz}{\left ( z^2-1 \right )} \right |\leq \frac{\pi}{3}$$
>   I have an uneasy feeling that my inequality is incorrect.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The development in the OP was fine.  As an alternative, we can parameterize the curve $C$ by letting $z=2e^{i\phi}$, $0\le \phi\le \pi/2$.  Then, we have the estimates

$$\begin{align}
\left|\int_C\frac{1}{z^2-1}\,dz\right|&=\left|\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{i2e^{i\phi}}{4e^{i2\phi}-1}\,d\phi\right|\\\\
&\le 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{|4e^{i2\phi}-1|}\,d\phi\\\\
&\le 2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{||4e^{i2\phi}|-1|}\,d\phi\\\\
&=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{1}{3}\,d\phi\\\\
&=\frac\pi3
\end{align}$$

as was to be shown!